# Regular expression to parse YAML list

Tags: java, regex, yaml, lookbehind

I've got a YAML list like this and need to parse it with a regular expression in Java:

```
stacks:
  - name: test1
    folder: a
  - name: test2
    folder: b
```

In the end I would like to iterate the list text blocks. That means after creating a Pattern instance, I'd like the Matcher instance for this text to find two matches:

1.

```
name: test1
folder: a
```

2.

```
name: test2
folder: b
```

When ignoring the list name ("stacks" above), I could do the following:

```
String regex = "^\\s++-(.*$\\n(?:^\\s++[^-].*$\\n)*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.UNIX_LINES );
Matcher m = p.matcher( data );
```

A matcher generated with this expression would find the two matches that I need.

However, I actually don't want to ignore the list name and I would like to state "take all list elements after the following list name" (like a method call `getListData(yamlData, listName)`). It seems that I would need a positive backward lookbehind. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to do this while still getting two matches. Do you have any idea?

*(I know there is snakeyaml and other libraries. Unfortunately, I need to use regular expressions here.)*

**Edit**: I can't make any assumptions about the order of the elements of the listed objects. A solution must be able to deal with name and folder (and potentially others) swapped.

Comment: so you want `getListData` to return all the name-folder pairs in it..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Yes, it should return whatever list items there are as a list. In the example above it should return a list ["name: test1\nfolder: a", "name: test2\nfolder: b"]